# Modular Inverse involving division of two numbers

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, modular-arithmetic

I know that  (a/b)mod M = ab^-1 mod M

and also that when M is prime then b^-1 = b^(M-2)

I have to calculate (121/2)mod M where M = 1000000007 (1e9 + 7)

**Using simple division**: (121/2)modM = (60)mod M  = 60%M = **60**

**Using modular Inverse**: (121/2)mod M = ( (121 mod M ) * ( 2 ^(M-2) mod M) ) mod M.

2 ^(M-2) mod M here is 500000004 (link: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~dsri/modular-inversion-answer.php?n=2&p=1000000007)

so the above expression becomes (121 mod M * 500000004)mod M = 60500000484 mod M = **500000064**

What am i possibly doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't perform integer division and expect to get the same result. You calculation should really be:

`121/2 (mod M) = 60 + 1/2 (mod M) = 60 + 50000004 = (mod M) = 50000064`

and not

`121/2 (mod M) = 60 (mod M)`

Since there is no definition of a `floor` function from the rational numbers `Q` into group [Z_n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) (only defined for rational numbers into natural numbers, `floor: Q -> N`) you should treat the divisions in [Z_n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) as you would with rationals, that is using remainders.

Comment: I am doing integer division because that is how the solution is to be derived for the problem I am solving. I have to output the answer modulo M. The final answer is of the form floor(A/2). The numerator is formed after after a series of steps of addition and multiplication so I take mod M at every step with the numerator. At the end I only have A%M and not the actual A

Comment: @lassaendie could you link the problem

Comment: I am afraid I cannot because I have to solve it myself. It would be cheating on my part to upload it

Comment: @lassaendie so  what exactly is the your problem then? are you asking why your calculations yield different results? the answer for `121/2 (mod M)` is indeed `500000064`

Comment: nope. answer for 121/2 should be 60. But as you said 121/2 mod M is indeed 500000064 then I suppose I am stuck. I am 100% sure the answer is right. :/
Or maybe there is another way to approach the same problem. Is there a way I can communicate the problem to you without disclosing it in public?

Comment: @lassaendie `answer for 121/2 should be 60` why do you think so? who says so?

Comment: Because The answer is floor(121/2)

Comment: @lassaendie `floor(121/2) = 60` but not under `mod M`. You **can't** apply `floor`  function when you using `mod M`. The floor function is defined for natural numbers as `floor: N -> N` but when using `mod M` you work in the set `Z_M` which completely different set from `N`

Comment: That is exactly what i require.

Comment: @lassaendie `That is exactly what i require.`. And what is that? Coming up with `floor` function for `Z_M`

Comment: It took me some time to understand the answer. I think it would be worth to say that exact divisions behave exactly like the integer counter-part. The problem is always the remainder.